# Drag an item from WebView to outside of UWP app

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

I have a C# UWP app which consists of a `WebView`, and I want to let the user drag an element from inside the WebView, to outside of the UWP app.

More technically, I want to transfer the control over the drag operation from the WebView to the C# code of the UWP app itself. The reason is that the WebView can't access the full data that's required for the drag&drop operation to be completed.

Using my own implementation, the WebView can notify the C# code about drag operation being started, but I still need to delegate the control over the drag operation itself from the web code into C# code.
I've tried to use [`startDragAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.startdragasync) but then the event handler for `DragStarting` (along with `DropCompleted`) is fired only when the **drop** (originated from the WebView) is done.

Is there any way in which the C# code could be notified when there's a start of a drag in the WebView, and gain control over it?

Comment: When I drag an element inside the WebView to drop onto another element in xaml which allows drop, it can trigger the Drop event in c# code. In addition, what do you mean about "the WebView can't access the full data that's required for the drag&drop operation to be completed" and have you used winrt api in js?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Thanks, but that's not what I'm aiming for. I want the C# code to fire an event when the drag starts - not just when it ends. The JS access to C# API in this app is limited only to my own classes, for security reasons.

Comment: If you want to trigger the DragStarting event in c# when you start dragging, it seems not feasible to achieve it.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT can you maybe explain why, please? or link to resources that show that?

Comment: When you drag the elements inside webview, the control is on the webview, and we can not transfer the control to the c#, that is, directly trigger DragStarting event in c#. We can only notify the c# when the drag starts.